# Hit a wall setting up company-irony with weird project structure/build system

Tags: company-mode, irony-mode

### Overview

I working on an OS project. It only uses header-files provided by the project code-base. The CMake meta-build, and ninja build system seems to be unrecognized by compilation and code-completion system out-of-the box. I've solved the syntax-checker, and I provide the solution for context.

For code-completion, it's working in parts. I think it's running on `company-etags`, which gets the function names, but not the rest of the signature. I'm after a solution that can include the arg-types in the code-completion.

**Suspected cause**: file structure confusing the company backend

Extract of the code-base structure. `.` is the repository root.
The

```
.
├── build
│   ├── build.ninja
│   ├── CMakeCache.txt
│   ├── CMakeFiles
│   ├── rules.ninja
│   ├── projects
│   │   ├── ...

    ...
    ...
├── CMakeLists.txt -> tools/seL4/cmake-tool/default-CMakeLists.txt
├── init-build.sh -> projects/aos/init-build.sh
├── .gitignore -> projects/aos/.gitignore
├── projects
│   ├── aos <- all development happens in here. 
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   ├── .gitignore
│   │   ├── compile_commands.json
│   │   ├── init-build.sh
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
        ...
│   │   ├── some-aos-proj-lib
│   │   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   │   ├── include
│   │   │   │   └── aos
│   │   │   │       ├── some-lib-file.h
│   │   │   │       ├── another-lib-file.h
│   │   │   └── src
│   │   │       ├── irq.h <- location of one func sig that completion needs
│   │   │       ├── ...
│   ├── some-lib <- the sub-dirs of libs at this level
│   │   ├── ... <- contain a bunch of .h files needed for code completion
│   ├── another-lib 
│   │   ├── ...
        ...
...
```

initially `/build` is empty. To build the project:

```
$ cd build
$ ../init-build.sh
$ ninja
```

### Problem

I've solved the compile-time problem of the header-file resolution of the default `M-x projectile-project-compile` (`<.h>` and `".h"`), but code completion is **still name only** (seems to be running on an `etags` backend.

```lisp
  ;; runs a ninja build from the path in .build-dir
  (projectile-register-project-type 'ninja '(".build-dir")
                                    :compile "ninja -C `cat .build-dir`")
```

NOTE: `.build-dir` has the single line `/full/path/to/build`, so `ninja` happens in `/build`

### Stuck!

So now we come to where I'm stuck: code-completion.

In trying to solve this code-completion problem, this is what I've learned

- `company` needs a backend.
- The `irony` backend can work with a compilation database (cdb)
- The `ninja` build system can generate the cdb for `irony`
- There is some sort of mechanism for`company-irony` to use a cdb for completion.

referencing [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28026/add-include-paths-to-flycheck-and-to-company-irony), we get to see a hint at what to do. Because this project I'm working on is structured differently, I'm not so sure about where my project root, and what paths to add to compile-command, as far as company is concerned.

Comment: This question could use some info on your `irony` and `company-irony` configuration.

Comment: For strictly use of irony, see this example: http://www.coli.uni-saarland.de/~slemaguer/emacs/main.html#org83b295c; however if you like to a more efficient method(s) use the *lsp-mode* (https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/lsp-mode.html#lsp-clangd) - and a good working configuration is here: https://www.mortens.dev/blog/emacs-and-the-language-server-protocol/index.html